# Get Crescent Moon, Cluster in Cluster Datasets

Tags: dataset, cluster-analysis

I looking for datasets whose labels are categorical where the clusters formed by these different labels form particular visualizations:

- Crescent moon;
- Cluster in a cluster;
- 4 clusters well distributed in space;
- 2 cluster well distributed in space;
- 2 or/and 3 stretched clusters;
- Clusters with outliers;
  Etc.
  Thank you!

[image: Example1]

[image: Example2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this kind of data, I used scikit-learn's data generation.

[data genration scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_linkage_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-linkage-comparison-py)